# Passing lazy loaded Fluent Nhibernate POCO to multiple worker threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, poco

I'm looking for a bit of advice on what can be done with POCO instances, lazy loaded by Nhibernate (Fluent NHibernate if it makes any difference).

I'm working on a generic implementation for change logging. Reason for doing a completely custom implementation is that change data has to be written in a very specific format to be used for different purposes. Not all information needed can be directly accessed from POCO instance but has to be calculated instead. End result is, change data will be written to a database separate from operational database. The act of writing the data will be done using SqlCommand.

Because the implementation has to be generic to support current POCO classes as well as any future additions it will use Reflection to extract properties of a POCO passed to the change logging implementation.

What I have is:

```
public interface IChangeLogger
{
    void Log(BaseEntity entity);
}
```

where BaseEntity is a class every POCO inherits from.

The implementation is

```
public class DefaultChangeLogger : IChangeLogger
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public DefaultChangeLogger()
    { 
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ChangeLogger"];
        Guard.Against<ConfigurationErrorsException>(connectionString == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString.ConnectionString));
        _connectionString = connectionString.ConnectionString;
    }

    public void LogChange(BaseEntity entity)
    {
        var logger = new SqlServerDirectChangeLogger(_connectionString, entity);
        var starter = new ThreadStart(logger.Log);
        var workerThread = new Thread(starter) { IsBackground = true };
        workerThread.Start();
    }
}
```

And then finally the final worker implementation:

```
public class SqlServerDirectChangeLogger
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;
    private readonly BaseEntity _entity;

    public SqlServerDirectChangeLogger(string connectionString, BaseEntity entity)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
        _entity = entity;
    }

    public void Log()
    { 

    }
}
```

The reason behind having a separate thread is not to bog down the application (MVC3, IIS7.5) and instead do the formatting and logging in a low priority background thread. When front end user updates a record I don't want to delay the response because the logger needs to do it's bit synchronously.

So what the SqlServerDirectChangeLogger.Log() will be doing is using Reflection to extract property values and also load some additional meta data that is then written to change log tables in a separate database in key - value like format.

The issue is as follows:

1. Web applications use ISession scoped to PerWebRequest. The DefaultChangeLogger would have lifecycle of Singleton. If I am passing in a lazy Loaded POCO and evaluating properties which may trigger lazy loading, requiring an open ISession. ISession will likely be closed by the time it is needed.

Is it possible to get NHibernate to "finalize" a POCO instance? By finalize I mean to force lazy loading to a certain level and possibly disconnect the ISession?

Can I anticipate any other issues by passing an instance like above between IIS worker thread and spawned worker threads?

Any better idea on how to implement change logging? :)

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably just pass the id of the object to the worker thread and re-query it in that thread.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did think of this approach and it might be something I have to fall back to.